# Zxing PhoneGap Windows Only QR Code

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, zxing, barcode-scanner

I was wondering if anyone else has implemented the PhoneGap Barcode Reader
for the Windows Phone?

In the description it says it should be able to register more than just
QR code but i cannot simply get it to work. I am interested to extract 
the information from Code 128.

I have implemented the ZXing library for PhoneGap in Android environment 
with great success.

Are there any other alternatives out there for reading EAN Code 128
combined with the usage of PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the barcode scanner in Windows using [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner) PhoneGap Plugin. It works with a charm. Also, using ZXing library you can easily go for various options available. Like Code 128 !

Comment: That's the one i am currently using. I don't know why it only will work on QR codes. Is it possible that i need to customize it in order to get it to work? The Android version worked out of the box, i just installed the plugin with no modification whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah, modifications is must !! in every plugin, you need to modify according to your needs!

Comment: @MAST3RMIND Link not found.

Comment: Can you provide an update to a working link to this?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with changing version of the Zxing library and it solved my problem. Now everything seems to work as expected.